# java script is not working

Tags: php, javascript

i am comparing password and confirm password through java script.my code-

```
function validate_form(thisform)
{  
with (thisform)
  {  
    if (validate_required(password,"<b>Error: </b>Password must be filled out!")==false)  
  {password.focus();return false;}

  else if (validate_required(cnfpassword,"<b>Error: </b>Confirm Password must be filled out!")==false)
  {cnfpassword.focus();return false;}

  else if (document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('cnfpassword').value)
  {password.focus();Sexy.error("<b>Error: </b>Passwords entered are not same!"); 
  password.value="";cnfpassword.value="";return false;}
  }
```

**validate_required()** function is working fine, it is showing alert msg but **password compare** is not working. But the same code is working fine in some other page.I have written some php code to avoid page caching-

```
<?php
session_start();
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

**what's the problem???**

Comment: It might help if you show us the html for the form the password inputs are on. Both for the working page and the non-working page.

Comment: Why do you have if clauses that are doing a comparison to false? It is already a boolean value, you can just not it to make the false return produce a true if clause.

Comment: **javascript** - as in, "my snippet of javascript is not working". Not "my java script is not working". That implies you're programming a script, with java (which is a bit odd). Sorry - pet peeve.

Comment: @unholy ....how please can u write that line.

Comment: The `!` symbol is used to not the boolean result of your function and turn false to true. `!validate_required(password,"<b>Error: </b>Password must be filled out!")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange code !

What does the

```
with (thisform)
```

do ? 
Does it allow to have password and cnfpassword in the current scope ?

If so, why don't you do :

```
else if (password.value != cnfpassword.value)
```

?

Apart from this, I suggest you to validate the form ALSO in PHP.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/With

Comment: `with` is generally agreed to be a JavaScript mistake that should never be used. Unfortunately, the bloody awful example code on w3schools uses it, which is why we keep seeing this ugly and completely pointless `validate_required` function popping up again and again. Die, w3schools, die.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the values themselves; do you have a javascript debugger to help you step through and see where the error is happening? If you're using Firefox, I recommend the addon [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript).

Answer (score 0):

make sure the form input id's are correct (password and cnfpassword).
also if they are, you could try changing

```
if (document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('cnfpassword').value)
```

to

```
if (password.value != cnfpassword.value)
```